# simple element wise with Keras over TF

Tags: tensorflow, keras

i am trying to implement the following in TensorFlow:

```
Input * const
```

matrix multiplication of 640x800x6
 Here is the code 
    ssValues = np.zeros(shape=(6,640,800),dtype=np.float16)

```
inputPlaceHolder = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(shape=(6,640,800), name='InputTensor', dtype=tf.dtypes.float16)
inputLayer = tf.keras.Input(shape=(6,640,800,),
                            batch_size=1,
                            name='inputLayer',
                            dtype=tf.dtypes.float16,
                            tensor=inputPlaceHolder)

ssConstant = tf.constant(ssValues, dtype=tf.dtypes.float16, shape=(6,640,800), name='ss')
ssm = tf.keras.layers.Multiply()([inputPlaceHolder,inputPlaceHolder])
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputLayer, outputs=ssm)

input = np.zeros(shape=(6,640,800),dtype=np.float16)

output = model.predict(input)
```

i get the following error:
ValueError: ('Error when checking model input: expected no data, but got:', array([[[1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],

- how to overcome this error and run the predict function ?
- why tf.keras.layers.multiply doesn't return a Layer object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue comes from the fact that you declared your operation on a v1 placeholder, when it should simply use the `inputLayer` (which already acts as a placeholder for inputs following the provided specification).

Additionnally, you wrote a multiplication that returns $x \times x$, when I think you wanted $x \times constant$ ; so here would be the code:

```py
inputLayer = tf.keras.Input(shape=(6,640,800,),
                            batch_size=1,
                            name='inputLayer',
                            dtype=tf.dtypes.float16)
ssConstant = tf.constant(  # also fixed a shape issue here
    ssValues, dtype=tf.dtypes.float16, shape=(1, 6,640,800), name='ss'
)
ssm = tf.keras.layers.Multiply(dtype=tf.dtypes.float16)([inputLayer, ssConstant])
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputLayer, outputs=ssm)

inputs = np.zeros(shape=(1,6,640,800), dtype=np.float16)
output = model.predict(inputs)
```

Furthermore, since this is not an actual model, in the sense that it uses a constant and not learnable weights, you might want to use `tf.keras.backend.function` instead of `tf.keras.Model` (but that is really up to you).

Note that the shapes are probably not suited to what you actually want, with the batch-size of 1... Please consider using a batch-size of 6 to remove the useless dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `Input(shape)` you have a placeholder already. It doesn't make sense to create a placeholder to the pass it to `Input(tensor=placeholder)` because this is not how Keras works.

You must:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(6,640,800))
ssm_tensor = Multiply()([inputs, inputs])
model = Model(inputs, ssm)
```

Since you always have a batch size with Keras:

```
input = np.zeros(shape=(1,6,640,800))
```